# how can i have angular2 update content after dynamically loading a component

Tags: angular, dynamic

I have angular2 final version. Have created a component

```
  @Component({
    selector:'artists',
    template: `
      <h2>Artists Information</h2>
      <ul [style.display]="artists?.length>0 ? 'block':'none'">
        <li ngfor="a in artists">Name: {{a?.name}} - Followers:  {{a?.folloers.total}}</li>
      </ul>
       `
  })
  export class Artists{
    @Input("list")
    private artists:any;
  }
```

at a later time somewhere in the program i try to dynamically load the component

```
  @ViewChild('divBody', {read: ViewContainerRef}) private body: ViewContainerRef;

  this.body.clear();
  let factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(Artists);
  let injector = ReflectiveInjector.fromResolvedProviders([], this.body.parentInjector);   
  let b= this.body.createComponent(factory,0,injector,[]);

  // data is comming from an ajax call to a remote location.
  b.instance.artists = data.artists.items;
  b.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
```

My problem is that the Artists view is not updated and shows a blank list row instead of list of artists.

Question is what am i missing? why template is not update with data even after i call detectChanges() ????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<li ngfor="a in artists"
```

should be

```
<li *ngFor="let a of artists"
```

If you have no `null` elements in `artists` you don't need `?` in `{{a?.name}}` (within `*ngFor`)

Comment: Thank you very much. that little change fixed the problem.

Comment: @Masoud if the answer solves your problem, please consider accepting the answer using the checkmark below the up/down-vote button to indicate your problem is solved.

Comment: I've added bunch of samples on plunker.. hope they become used by the public... "https://plnkr.co/users/msalehisedeh"